# attachment not getting returned with get_posts

Tags: wordpress, attachment

I'm working in a function, something link this:

```
function just_in_case_featured($size) {
    global $post;
    $plan_b_featured_url = [];
    $featured_image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, $size);
    $attachments = get_posts(array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberpost' => 1,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID
    ));
    if ($featured_image_url) {
        return $featured_image_url;
    } else if ($attachments ) {
        $plan_b_featured_url = $attachments[0]->guid;
        return $plan_b_featured_url;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This function is meant to return the first image of the post's attachments array in case the post is lacking a featured image.

There are two problems:

1. When I remove an image from a post, that attachment remains having the same post_parent in the wp_post table, and that sucks since you may include that image in another post and there is no way to relate it to that new post since it keeps the old post_parent value at the db. Also if you include an image in the content without Feat. image it works, but then you remove it and the image keeps being returned since at the db the image's inicial post_parent value remains.
2. Attachments have the 'inherit' value as post_status since these inherit their status from the post_parent. Problem is i cannot load an image using the function above (it worked with standard format, the problem appears to be with an audio formatted post) unless i edit manually the db and change inherit to publish (the post is surely published), once I make that edition to the db then I can retrieve it. The weird stuff is that if I var_dump get_post_status($attachment_ID) it returns publish!! >-( So, then the inherit property is working but for some reason the attachments is not getting returned.

Comment: What is the value that you are getting while doing var_dump($plan_b_featured_url)?

Comment: if I var_dump $attachments i get an empty array, $plan_b_featured_url is just attachments's first element so

Answer (score 0):

Ok, **SOLVED** ***the second problem*** like this:

```
function just_in_case_featured($size) {
    global $post;
    $attachments = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
        'post_per_page' => 1
        ));
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $featured_image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID , $size );
        } else if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID );
    } 
        } else {
    $featured_image = false;
    }
    return $featured_image;
}
```

The first problem remains, which is more of structural wordpress stuff, I know you can detach manually the images in the admin panel, but the question is why do i have to.

Something else to point out: the first parameter of `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` which is normally the `$post->ID` is documented as optional, when in many cases just isn't and the function, even if doesn't cause an error just doesn't work.